# I am confused with a lookahead/lookbehind regular expression not working

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I want to parse the following string

```
void int g = <span id="sentenceColor">"c int void x is "</span> + 4;
```

I want to find void and int that is outside the  element not inside the  element. I have the following regular expression.

```
(?<!<span id="sentenceColor">.*)((int)|(void))(?!.+(<\/span>))
```

I am assuming the above means find int or void with a lookbehind making sure I do not have  followed by an indeterminate amount of characters. Also making sure that these words are no followed by an indeterminate amount of characters and . I've been using an online regex tester for a while and figured maybe someone has better experience with this than I.

Comment: What regex have to do with html ???

Comment: Is this a whole input string? or input string contains this line? and what is the language?

Comment: There is no language here. This is not html. I am creating html through information gained from regular expressions. The html is because this the resulting string i have at this particular point. Everything is getting handled in Java, but I am reading .txt files for this information.

Comment: So the language is Java. Please tag your question with it. A specific language or tool should be tagged with regex questions otherwise we'd have no idea to answer.

Comment: No. The language is not Java. I am using an online tool called regex101 to build the regular expression. I am currently using java but what if someone wants to use the answer here in C++, Python, or PHP, or whathaveyou. The question is not geared to any specific language but to the fundamental usage of lookahead or lookbehind in regular expressions. I'm looking for a pattern that works for regular expressions outside of any library or language. the fact I am using java is just the language I am using at the time. What if I want to use this in another language?

Comment: Firstly - do you want to capture the `void int` that come **before** the tag? So why did you use look-behind? Secondly, it **is** important to know if you're using Javascript, because it doesn't allow lookbehind

Answer (score 1):

Your regex suffers from a few mistakes:

1. It uses look-behind with a dynamic length string, which is [invalid](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> Many regex flavors, including those used by Perl, Python, and Boost **only allow fixed-length strings**. You can use literal text, character escapes, Unicode escapes other than \X, and character classes. **You cannot use quantifiers** or backreferences...

2. You mentioned you want to match `void` **and** `int`, but you use the OR operator: `((int)|(void))`, which will cause the regex to match only one of them.
3. Redundant parenthesis, which create many [groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (although not crucial, it's definitely not a great habit).

If you want to match the `void` and `int` inside the tag you can use this regex, that uses look**before** properly:

```
(?<=<span id="sentenceColor">).*(void int|int void)
```

Or if you want to match those before the tag, you should use look**ahead**; and this would be the regex you're after:

```
(void int|int void).*(?=<span id="sentenceColor">)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as long I know, you *can't* use *quantifiers* with lookbehind :/.
So, your '*' will not work and cause an error.  I don't know how to solve your problem yet, but will keep trying to give a solution and, at least, you know the reason why it's not working.
**[EDIT]:**
well, the following *RegEx* `(\".*?\")` selects the content between ' " '.
So, a solution I've come up with is to *remove* from the original string the result of the match with this regex and, then, simply use `(int|void)` on the new string.
Hope this helps.
**[EDIT 2]:**
below, the error *Regex101* shows.
`lookbehind assertion is not fixed length - offset: 31`
[image]

Comment: Could you provide some documentation to substantiate the claim that one cannot use quantifiers with lookbehind? For what regex flavours does it hold?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin just pay attention on the "Match information" section at "Regex101" when you paste `(?<!<span id="sentenceColor">.*)((int)|(void))(?!.+(<\/span>))
` as a regex

Comment: Well, yes, thanks for the hint (that's a really good advice, I gonna use it). But your posting literally starts with the words "I don't know how to solve your problem". Despite that, the question of the OP is now showed in the queues as having at least one answer (therefore, it doesn't show up in the 'unanswered'-queue). Do you have an answer, or do you have no answer? I'm not the OP, I'm just a random guy from the review queue...

Comment: My first comment was rather a hint that you should make a waterproof argument why what the OP wants is not possible at all. Sometimes, [this, too, counts as an answer, as in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2707792). However, if you just say "I don't know how to solve it", and you have 11 rep, and you have images in your answer, then the system will most likely put your answer into the review queue. Otherwise, it would make the question appear as "answered", and prevent it from being *actually* answered.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin thanks for the tip. You're right, will pay attention at this next time :)